# Should I use IQ data or power data to compare 2 signals through `similaritymeasures.dtw`?

Tags: python, time-series, amplitude, time-domain, waveform-similarity

I choose `similaritymeasures.dtw` to compare experiment signal `exp_sig` and reference signal ref_sig.
Both signals are I,Q data collected from Gnuradio.

```
exp_sig = np.reshape([[1+1*1j, 1+2*1j,2+1*1j, 3+2*1j,3+1*1j, 3+2*1j,4+1*1j, 3+2*1j,5+1*1j, 7+2*1j]],(-1,1))
ref_sig = np.reshape([[1+1*1j, 1+2*1j, 2+1*1j, 3+2*1j, 3+1*1j, 2+2*1j, 4+1*1j, 2+2*1j, 5+1*1j, 2+2*1j, 6+1*1j, 2+2*1j, 7+1*1j, 2+2*1j, 8+1*1j, 4+2*1j]],(-1,1))
```

**As DTW is `dynamic time warping`,should I construct `magnitude` from `I` and `Q`,then `similaritymeasures.dtw(magnitude)` to compare?**

What I tried:

```
dtw, d = similaritymeasures.dtw(exp_sig, ref_sig)
plt.plot(d)
```

[image]

Calculate `amplitude`,then `dtw`,and plot.

```
exp_sig =np.abs(exp_sig)
ref_sig =np.abs(ref_sig)
dtw, d = similaritymeasures.dtw(exp_sig, ref_sig)
plt.plot(d)
```

[image]

We found `similaritymeasures.dtw` output differenct result with IQ data and power data.

When I compare 2 signals through `similaritymeasures.dtw`,should I use raw IQ data or power data?

Comment: In order to give you any meaningful answer, you would have add A LOT more detail. What are these signals (physically), what properties of them might affect the health of mice, where do reference and signal come from, what's the physical mechanism that makes them different and why does it matter that they are different, etc.

Comment: @Hilmar,in the signal processing,should I use `IQ data` or `power data` to compare 2 signals through `similaritymeasures.dtw`?That's my question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @kittygirl Hilmar didn't ask you to repeat what you wrote! I think we could help you much better if you re-read Hilmar's comment very closely and answered all 5 questions he asked!

Comment: @kittygirl *removing* information when asked to provide more context is counter-productive! And four out of five of Hilmar's questions were not concerned with mice at all.

Comment: @MarcusMüller,we are discussing signal process here,no matter with mice any more.

Comment: @kittygirl honestly, I still don't see the discussion: To answer "what should I do?", we need to know "for what purpose, under what constraints, with what signals?" That's what Hilmar asked. You still need to answer that – we still can't see inside your head to know what the purpose of all this is, and we really can't answer your question.